# Recover save games in Far cry 3

Tags: far-cry-3, windows-8

I completed Far Cry 3 around 60% and I had to refresh my windows 8 pc due to some internet issues. During a refresh all desktop apps will be uninstalled but no files will be lost. So I thought the save files won't be affected. But after the refresh, I installed Far Cry 3 and I get no option to continue! 
Please help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try recovering the save games (which are located on `C:\Program Files (x86)\Ubisoft\Ubisoft Game Launcher\savegames` on Windows 8) using a program like [Recuva](http://www.piriform.com/recuva). This allows you to find back deleted files and recover them. This will have less success each time you download/install something new on your computer. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried recuva but no luck. I think its because after the refresh I installed so many softwares. I think I have to play it again >:[

Comment: Possible yes. When you delete something from your hard disk, the data actually gets a status of 'I can be overwritten'. So it isn't really deleted untill other data overwrites that.